# Set multiple images on screen supporting multiple density

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing a simple game part of application where i need to create a game using lots of images of different different shapes, imagine ice breaker game where i need to break ice using hammer.

So when i think of **setting layout** with different types of ice images and that too which support all different densities,i get stuck and not able to understand how i set my layout, **whether with Relative / Linear Layout** so that it give me same result in all size of android devices except tablets.

I hope you understood the problem, support of all density, around 500-600 images with different shapes, which layout to use and one more thing .apk size is also big matter for me as there are other lots of images other than for this game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the [Screen Supports](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for the better understanding.

Use configuration qualifiers as explain in that Document for the Different Layout. And Also put the XML file with in that layout drawable directory.

that help me. So it will be also helpful to you.

Be free to comment if you have any dought.

**Edited**

You can set the layout for the different screen support as like below:

See the Image Below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but does that mean i have to create separate xml files under different folders (layout-small,layout-normal and layout-large) or for different densities (layout-ldpi and so on), or there is any other way around? As i said i have images with different shapes, try to imagine mountain of ice with full of images, so it is not easy to set layout, so which layout to use in this case and is it necessary to create different layout files under different folders as you suggested above. I tried to set layout but i got to take 500-600 imageviews to set those 600 images. Need your suggestion.

Comment: @Ankit Please put final image what you want?  you might have the final result image. And i will help you in that case. And also wait for my edited answer.

Comment: @Ankit: See updated Answer for help regarding the different Layout file.

Comment: Hi i guess, this would work. I can do above thing for my game section and then normal layout for other app section. Lemme try this and then i will select it as answer.

Comment: @Ankit: Yes, it will surly works. as it works for me in many app. And you can also give some specific static size to the Some desire layout with their desire layout xml file.

Comment: @ iDroid Explorer **static size to some desired layout** does that mean i can use AbsoluteLayout as well?

Comment: @Ankit: not it dosent mean like that. I mean you can define the specific size to the Some ImageView while you displaying in different layout and if needed to make it little big or small in size.

Comment: @Ankit : Thanks budy. Keep coding. :)